# Replace and filter value Error: 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.'

Tags: python

I've this df:

```
VELWIND
0
1
34
54
2
3
25
```

What I'm trying to do is filter values between 0 and 30, and write `nan` if `df >= 30`. The `df.type` is `float64`

I have this code:

```
df['VELWIND_filt']=df.loc[(df['VELWIND'] > 0) & (df['VELWIND'] < 30) & (df['VELWIND'] >=30, np.nan)]
```

but I have this error:

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

I was testing that it gave an error, and it is this part specifically:

```
(df['VELWIND'] >=30, np.nan)
```

EDIT SOLVED:

I solved this problem used this line:

`df['VELWIND_filt'] = np.where((df['VELWIND'] < 0) | (df['VELWIND'] >= 30), np.nan, df['VELWIND'])`

Comment: There are two things here: filter between 0 and 30 and write nan to >= 30. what is your expected output?

Comment: I expected a new column, that only contain values between 0 and 30

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df[(df['VELWIND'] < 0) | (df['VELWIND'] >= 30)] = np.nan
print(df)
```

If you want to add it as new column, create the new column first THEN make the changes:

```
df['VELWIND_FILT'] = df['VELWIND']
df[(df['VELWIND_FILT'] < 0) | (df['VELWIND_FILT'] >= 30)] = np.nan
print(df)
```

Comment: yes, that's it, but I also look for the new results to be added to a new column `df['VELWIND_filt']`

Comment: see edit in answer above